# Ordering variable listeners without dependencies

Tags: optaplanner

Is it possible to have control over the order of variable listeners without creating dependencies?  In this particular case I want to fire the AnchorVariableListener before firing CustomVariableListener.  I do not want them to have a dependency as CustomVariableListener may be fired when a variable changes it's order in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency won't prevent the CustomVariableListener to be fired when another variable changes it's order. For example:

```
@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = FooVariableListener.class,
        sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "orderIndex"),
                   @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "anchor")})
public Foo getFoo() {...}
```

In this case, the FooVariableListener will be called if orderIndex or anchor or both of them change. Note that both can be shadows too (or genuines, it doesn't matter). If both change, then both their values will be updated first, before `FooVariableListener` is called.

In this image, that shadow variable Foo is E:

[image]

Comment: I tried doing that, but the slowdown was enough that was not worth the improvement.  Without the dependency is it possible to control order?

Comment: No, it's not. But it's strange that you get a slowdown - the variable listeners should "short-circuit" (don't update fields if they are already that value).